# If $ x\in X $ is an accumulation point of set $ A$ in $ X$, is then $ f(x) $ an accumulation point of set $f(A) $ in $Y$? Where $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $ f \colon X \to Y $ a continuous function and  $ A \subset X$. If $ x\in X $ is an accumulation point of set $ A$ in $ X$, is then $ f(x) $ an accumulation point of set $f(A) $ in $Y$?

I can't find a counterexample but I am having trouble proving it because $f$ does not have to be bijective so equalities are not valid when looking at  inverse image of an image if a set and so on.  ( I used the characterisation of continuity that for every open set the inverse image is an open set)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\{0\}$ and $A=(0,1)$, then $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$, but $f(0)$ is not an accumulation point of $\{0\}$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(y) $ have to be an element of $ f(A) $ without the set $ \left\{f(x) \right\} $? What if $ f(x) =f(y) $, that is what if $f$ is not injective?

Comment: @user15269 I agree with you.

Comment: @user15269 Good point, that immediately gives rise to the counter-example above.